# select date mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime, select

I have a date in this format: `$originalDate = '2011-05-19T15:39:06Z'`

I store it in a `datetime` `mysql` field. 
In phpMyAdmin the date is displayed in this format:`2011-05-19 15:39:06`

Now I want to select all mysql entries `WHERE date = $originalDate`
But nothing is selected.

How do I do this?

cheers,
Joerg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert $originalDate to fit the MySQL DATETIME format:

First convert it to the integer format with PHP's strtotime(), and then convert that to MySQL format with PHP's date(), and THEN use it in the MySQL query.

EDIT: Code:

```
$mysqlDate = date('Y-m-d h:i:s',strtotime($originalDate));
```

Then use that for your WHERE statement:

```
WHERE `date` = '$mysqlDate'
```

Comment: I think this is the right way but 
$mysqlDate = date('Y-m-d h:i:s',strtotime($originalDate));

turns 2011-05-19T15:39:06Z

into 2011-05-19 05:39:06

Comment: @joerg this is the right way. if your prblem solved then accept the answer

Comment: joerg, turning it into 2011-05-19 05:39:06 is what you want, because that is the exact same format as the datetime stored in MySQL that you see in PHPmyAdmin. This allows for a direct comparison.

Comment: That's right, 
but there is a problem with the date format:
Y-m-d h:i:s 
turns 2011-05-19T15:39:06Z into 2011-05-19 05:39:06
So 15:39:06 becomes 05:39:06

Y-m-d H:i:s
turns 2011-05-19T15:39:06Z into 2011-05-19 17:39:06
so 05 becomes 17

It might be a timezone problem... Any idea

Comment: The Z in your original date implies UTC time. Your php setup probably has a default timezone set, and it's transferring it to that timezone. I believe you can check the timezone you're using with date_default_timezone_get().

Comment: There you go. So you could also use str_replace() to replace the T and Z with spaces, given that they're the only alphabetic characters in your date. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php . Replace T and Z with spaces, then skip the date and strtotime functions and just straight find it with WHERE in SQL. Now feel free to accept my answer :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Best from Berlin!

Answer (score 2):

You need to put quotes around the date you are using to compare against, and I'm sure you need to remove the "T" and "Z" characters from the $originalDate ...

E.g.

```
$originalDate = '2011-05-19 15:39:06'
```

And the where clause should look like this;

```
WHERE `date` = '$originalDate'
```

Note the back-ticks (`) around the field name, as "date" is a MySQL reserved word / functions.